# Jquery,Php $_POST value always empty

Tags: php, jquery

I want to insert data in my data base once the user clicks on "Add" Button. I got values using Jquery:
Here is Jquery code :

```
 $.post('process.php',
      {
          name: 'aaaaa',
          id: '1'
      }, function(data) {
          alert(data);
  });
```

And here is the Php Code:

This code is never executed!

```
  if((!empty($_POST['name']))&&(!empty($_POST['id']))){
      $nomp = $_POST['name'];
      $idtp=$_POST['id'];
      echo $nomp;
      $conn = dbConn();
      $add="Insert into prod(nomp,idtp) values ('".$nomp."',".$idtp.") ";
      $conn->query($add);
      $conn=null;
}
```

I want to understand why and what should I do to fix this problem!

Comment: You're using empty function in wrong way.

Comment: isset also does not work for me, and what is the prob with empty function!

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network to see what is sent and status. Add some error handling to both ends

Comment: Now it works but echo $nomp; still  does not work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd always validate if is set, instead of empty:

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])&&isset($_POST['id'])){
  //then in here I throw a foreach validating and sanitizing every required field in case that everyone are
}else{
   //throw error 
}
```

The else I think is pretty important at least testing or debbuging when you are working with ajax post, you can discard quickly errors this way.

Tell me if this works for you!

Comment: Of course it does, but if you first check if is set then you avoid the "undefined" error from variables in case they aren't post (this is mostly for having a clean log), then inside you validate if is empty, which it could be

Answer (score 0):

You forget to put the quote around the second value ( $idtp)

```
 $add="Insert into prod(nomp,idtp) values ('".$nomp."',’".$idtp."’) ";
```

Answer (score -1):

It must be like below:

```
if((int)$_POST['id']>0 && strlen($_POST['name'])>0){
      $nomp = $_POST['name'];
      $idtp=$_POST['id'];
      echo $nomp;
      $conn = dbConn();
      $add="Insert into prod(nomp,idtp) values ('".$nomp."',".$idtp.") ";
      $conn->query($add);
      $conn=null;
}
```

Make changes to js function:

```
$.post('process.php',
      {
          name: 'aaaaa',
          id: '1'
      }, function(data) {
          alert(data);
  }, 'json');
```

Comment: Why *"must it"* be that way?

Comment: Not must be, sometimes empty function even counts not just passed value, even more.

Comment: If the block doesn't get executed, it's better to try something else.